# write CRLF at the end of string: android post SOAP

Tags: java, android, newline, ksoap2

I need to post a SOAP request from my android app to a windows server. Part of this request is a string of many products code, prices and so one. I must write this string with CRLF for windows system at the end of every line. I can't understand beacuse if write this code:

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer()
while(condition){
   str.append("something")
   str.append((char)(Integer.parseInt("0D", 16))); //CR
   str.append((char)(Integer.parseInt("0A", 16))); //LF
}
```

If I inspect `str` variable in debug apparently is ok, but if I use a hexadecimal editor like bless, and I paste into this content of `str` variable, the end of every line not contains `0D 0A` but only '0A'.
I can't understand the trouble! I don't now this is the correct way but I need to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: It may be possible that it's just a copy/paste problem. The carriage return character may be filtered out while doing so. You could just print the string into a file and open that with your hex editor in order to verify if there is still a problem

Comment: Oh mine! Yes this is possible, I try to use this way to post request